# 'Enemy' was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

Okay, so thats my error: 'Enemy' was not declared in this scope.The error is in the map.h file, even though map.h includes enemy.h as shown

```
#ifndef MAP_H_INCLUDED
#define MAP_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "enemy.h"

#define MAX_TILE_TYPES 20

using namespace std;

class Map{
        public:
        Map();
        void loadFile(string filename);
        int** tile;
        int** ftile;
        bool solid[MAX_TILE_TYPES];
        int width;
        int height;
        int tileSize;

        vector<Enemy> enemies;

};

#endif // MAP_H_INCLUDED
```

And here is enemy.h

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H_INCLUDED
#define ENEMY_H_INCLUDED

#include "global.h"
#include "map.h"

class Enemy{
        public:
        Enemy();
        Enemy(float nx, float ny, float nstate);
        void update(Map lv);
        bool rectangleIntersects(float rect1x, float rect1y, float rect1w, float rect1h, float rect2x, float rect2y, float rect2w, float rect2h);
        void update();
        float x;
        float y;
        Vector2f velo;
        float speed;
                float maxFallSpeed;
        int state;
        int frame;
        int width;
        int height;

        int maxStates;
        int *maxFrames;

        int frameDelay;

        bool facingLeft;
        bool onGround;

        bool dead;
        int drawType;
};

#endif // ENEMY_H_INCLUDED
```

Anyone know whats going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Which source file(.cpp, .c, .cc, etc...) was being compiled when you got this error? What does it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove one of the `#include` statements to break the circular reference. To allow the code to compile you can declare one of the included classes as just a simple definition

```
class Map;
```

in the top of the Enemy.hpp file, for example, and then include the header in the cpp file.

Answer (score 6):

`enemy.h` includes `map.h`

but, `map.h` includes `enemy.h`

So, if you include `enemy.h`, the processing will go something like this:

- ENEMY_H_INCLUDED gets defined
- global.h is included
- map.h is included

  - MAP_H_INCLUDED gets defined
  - enemy.h gets included

    - ENEMY_H_INCLUDED is already defined, so we skip to the end of the file
  - class Map gets defined

    - error, Enemy has not been defined yet

to fix this, remove `#include "map.h"` from `enemy.h`, and replace it with a forward declaration, `class Map;`

You will also need to modify `void update(const Map& lv);`  -- use a const&

and include "map.h" in `enemy.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

There is a circular dependency in your includes: `map.h` is including `enemy.h` and `enemy.h` is including `map.h`

You must remove the circular inclusion.